# Python Logging - Disable logging from imported modules

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I'm using the Python logging module, and would like to disable log messages printed by the third party modules that I import.  For example, I'm using something like the following:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)
fh = logging.StreamHandler()
fh_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(lineno)d:%(filename)s(%(process)d) - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(fh_formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

This prints out my debug messages when I do a logger.debug("my message!"), but it also prints out the debug messages from any module I import (such as requests, and a number of other things).

I'd like to see only the log messages from modules I'm interested in.  Is it possible to make the logging module do this?

Ideally, I'd like to be able tell the logger to print messages from "ModuleX, ModuleY" and ignore all others.

I looked at the following, but I don't want to have to disable/enable logging before every call to an imported function:
[logging - how to ignore imported module logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27685568/logging-how-to-ignore-imported-module-logs)

Comment: related: [How to list all existing loggers using python.logging module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249304/how-to-list-all-existing-loggers-using-python-logging-module)

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The problem is that calling [`getLogger`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger) without arguments returns the *root* logger so when you set the level to `logging.DEBUG` you are also setting the level for other modules that use that logger.

You can solve this by simply *not* using the root logger. To do this just pass a name as argument, for example the name of your module:

```
logger = logging.getLogger('my_module_name')
# as before
```

this will create a new logger and thus it wont inadvertently change logging level for other modules.

---

Obviously you have to use `logger.debug` instead of `logging.debug` since the latter is a convenience function that calls the `debug` method of the root logger.

This is mentioned in the [Advanced Logging Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial). It also allows you to know which module triggered the log message in a simple way.

Comment: I am creating a logger with `__name__` r but I still see the logs from the imported modules. I am trying to configure logging with an ini configuration file.What should I do for that?

Comment: Creating a logger with `__name__` also did not work for me. Maybe because I'm using a standalone script and not a "module" ? What worked for me was to configure logging for imported modules (`matpplotlib`, in my case) via `logging.getLogger("matplotlib").setLevel(logging.WARNING)` and for my script via `logging.basicConfig`.

Comment: I just wanted to highlightthe value of your line "Obviously you have to use `logger.debug` instead of `logging.debug`". It's an easy mistake to make using _logging_ instead of _logger_ but it usurps all of the clever configuration you want to set up. I've spent the last couple of hours living this!

Comment: @bli There is a big difference between logging when developing a library vs when developing an executable. Basically: if you are writing a module/package which is meant to be imported you should **not** configure anything. The module should only contain the `logger = logging.getLogger('package.my_module')` and your could calls `logger.debug/warning`, no configuring of logging levels or handlers. When you write the binary application *there* you should decide the level for the various logs and the handlers. Libraries that contain logging configuration will always be an issue.

Comment: In my case, the package I import uses the root logger (via `logging.info`). Is there any way to specifically disable root logs from this package?

Comment: I have no idea why this is so difficult in python. Its sad

Comment: @IanS No, that's why libraries should **not** use the root logger. Please open a bug report to that library and tell them to use `logging.getLogger(__name__)` instead.

Comment: @IanS Too late for you, I'm sure, but you can do this by adding a filter on the root logger. See my answer.

Comment: thanks @bmurr, it's never too late to learn ;)

Comment: This solution didn't work for me either. The only thing that worked was to set `logger.disabled = True` where I was defining the logger. Good enough for debugging without being flooded by INFO messages

Answer (score 79):

I was getting debug logs from matplotlib despite following the pretty straightforward documentation at the [logging advanced tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/logging.html#logging-advanced-tutorial)
and the [troubleshooting](https://matplotlib.org/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html). I was initiating my logger in `main()` of one file and importing a function to create a plot from another file (where I had imported matplotlib).

What worked for me was setting the level of matplotlib *before* importing it, rather than after as I had for other modules in my main file. This seemed counterintuitive to me so if anyone has insight into how you can set the config for a logger that hasn't been imported yet I'd be curious to find out how this works.

In my main file:

```
import logging
import requests
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('requests').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def main():
  ...
```

In my `plot.py` file:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('matplotlib').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def generatePlot():
  ...
```

Comment: I got error: 'Logger' object has no attribute 'DEBUG'. 
`logger.DEBUG` should be `logging.DEBUG`

Comment: Thanks! It really helps! I set matplotlib logging level after my main logging configuration and before the command which will import matplotlib. Solved!

Comment: I've set logging for `matplotlib` to `WARNING` **after** I've imported the module, since adding it before importing would give a lint-error. It still worked for me. I'm using `matplotlib==3.3.2` in Python 3.7 if it helps.

Comment: Had you tried `logging.getLogger('matplotlib.pyplot').setLevel(logging.WARNING)? (Since the application is actually importing `matplotlib.pyplot`.)

Answer (score 64):

If you're going to use the python `logging` package, it's a common convention to define a logger in every module that uses it.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

Many popular python packages do this, including [`requests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/__init__.py).  If a package uses this convention, it's easy to enable/disable logging for it, because the logger name will be the same name as the package (or will be a child of that logger).  You can even log it to the same file as your other loggers.

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

requests_logger = logging.getLogger('requests')
requests_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

handler = logging.StreamHandler()
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(handler)
requests_logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Comment: Be aware, that when you try to configure your loggers like in the official basic tutorial with `logging.basicConfig(...)` all loggers will now either output to `logging.lastResort` (starting with Python 3.2, which is stderr) if no handler was given or to the handler you set. So do not use it or you will continue getting all log messages anyway.

Answer (score 34):

This disables all existing loggers, such as those created by imported modules, while still using the root logger (and without having to load an external file).

```
import logging.config
logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
})
```

*Note that you need to import all modules you don't want logged first!* Otherwise those won't be considered as "existing loggers". It will then disable all loggers from those modules. This might lead you to also miss out on important errors!

For more detailed examples using related options for configuration, see https://gist.github.com/st4lk/6287746, and [here](https://gist.github.com/st4lk/6287746) is a (partially working) example using YAML for config with the `coloredlog` library.

Comment: This works for `request` for example, but it will not work when the imported modules create their loggers inside their class you'd call later, like the `APScheduler` does when you call `BackgroundScheduler.BackgroundScheduler()`. See here for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48891485/2441026

Comment: This works for my case with yaml configuration file

Comment: Note that you have to `import logging.config`, not just logging.

Comment: what if the imported module originally has a handler or something, does this also disable those handlers?

Answer (score 16):

After trying various answers in this thread and other forums, I found this method efficient at silencing other modules' loggers. This was inspired by the following link:

https://kmasif.com/2019-11-12-ignore-logging-from-imported-module/

```
import logging
# Initialize your own logger
logger = logging.getLogger('<module name>')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Silence other loggers
for log_name, log_obj in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.items():
     if log_name != '<module name>':
          log_obj.disabled = True
```

Note that you would want to do this after importing other modules. However, I found this to be a convenient and fast way to disabled other modules' loggers.

Comment: I used this and instead of disabling did logging.getLogger(log_name).setLevel(logging.WARNING)

Comment: That is a valid way to not silence an important log, by just increasing the log level (removing lower-level messages). Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 12):

You could use something like:

```
logging.getLogger("imported_module").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger("my_own_logger_name").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

This will set my own module's log level to DEBUG, while preventing the imported module from using the same level.

Note:
`"imported_module"` can be replaced with `imported_module.__name__` (without quotes), and `"my_own_logger_name"` can be replaced by `__name__` if that's the way you prefer to do it.

Answer (score 10):

@Bakuriu quite elegantly explains the function.  Conversely, you can use the `getLogger()` method to retrieve and reconfigure/disable the unwanted loggers.

I also wanted to add the `logging.fileConfig()` method accepts a parameter called `disable_existing_loggers` which will disable any loggers previously defined (i.e., in imported modules).

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by [@brendan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35326281/3250126), I created a simple `logger_blocklist` to which I can just all loggers I want to increase the level of. Thus, I was able to silence them all at once:

```py
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

logger_blocklist = [
    "fiona",
    "rasterio",
    "matplotlib",
    "PIL",
]

for module in logger_blocklist:
    logging.getLogger(module).setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

You can find the logger's name from the `format="%(name)s"` parameter, also included in `logging.basicConfig()`, for example: `DEBUG:matplotlib.font_manager:findfont: score(FontEntry(fname='/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/Ubuntu-R.ttf', name='Ubuntu', style='normal', variant='normal', weight=400, stretch='normal', size='scalable')) = 10.05`.

In this case you want to add the logger `matplotlib` to your block list.

As opposed to [@Finn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51529172/3250126) it was not necessary to have it outside `main()`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Another thing to consider is the [propagate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate) property of the Logger class.

For example, py-suds library for handling soap calls, even put to ERROR

```
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger('suds.transport').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger('suds.xsdschema').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger('suds.wsdl').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

logs logs about a module called sxbasics.py creationg a huge amount of logs

[image]

that because the propagation of the logs is True by default, setting to False, instead, i recovered 514MB of logs.

```
import logging
logging.getLogger("suds").propagate = False
logging.getLogger('suds.client').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger('suds.transport').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger('suds.xsdschema').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger('suds.wsdl').setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply doing something like this solves the problem:

```
logging.config.dictConfig({'disable_existing_loggers': True,})
```

> **NOTE**: Wherever you're placing this line, make sure all the imports everywhere in your project are done within that file itself. :)

Comment: AttributeError: module 'logging' has no attribute 'config'

Comment: @ciurlaro: import logging.config

Answer (score 3):

In the case that your imported module uses the root logger, then you can add a filter (https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects) on the root logger to remove unwanted logs:

```
class FilterUnwantedRecords():
    def filter(self, record):
        if '3rdpartymodule' in record.pathname:
            return False
        return True

logging.getLogger().addFilter(FilterUnwantedRecords())
```

Comment: This will not work since loggers don't propagate. The filter has to be attached to the handler used by the module. This is when the pain starts.

Comment: @omni Your comment does not make sense in the context of the imported module using only the root logger. Why would propagation be relevant? I've had exactly this situation and solved it with exactly this code.

Comment: From far the best solution, and the only one really answering to the question

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I have a logging_config.py file which I import in all other py files. 
In logging_config.py file I set root logger logging level to ERROR (by default its warning):

```
logging.basicConfig(
    handlers=[
        RotatingFileHandler('logs.log',maxBytes=1000, backupCount=2),
        logging.StreamHandler(), #print to console
    ],
    level=logging.ERROR
)
```

In other modules I import logging_config.py and declare a new logger and set its level to debug:

```
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

This way everything I log in my py files is logged, but stuff logged at debug and info level by imported modules like urllib, request,boto3 etc is not logged. If there is some error in those import module then its logged, since I set root loggers level to ERROR.

Answer (score 0):

```py
# mymodule.py

# Import 'logging' module from standard library
import logging

# Set all loggers to show only WARNING and above
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.WARNING)

# Create your module-specific logger (__name__ will be 'mymodule' in this example)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Set your desired logging level for your logger
logger.setLevel(level=logging.DEBUG)

# Add handlers if you want
fh = logging.StreamHandler()
fh_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(lineno)d:% filename)s(%(process)d) - %(message)s')
fh.setFormatter(fh_formatter)
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

Another example, this time using a helper function and the RichHandler from the [rich](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html) 3rd-party module.

```py
# loghelper.py
import logging
from rich.logging import RichHandler

def new_logger(logger_name: str) -> logging.Logger:
    FORMAT = "%(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.WARNING, format=FORMAT, datefmt="[%X]", handlers=[RichHandler()]
    )
    log = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    # Add handlers ...
    # ...
    return log
```

Then import the helper function into your module

```py
# mymodule.py

from loghelper import new_logger

# Nice and tidy!
logger = new_logger(__name__)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest solution I could find in order to **print exclusively the logging statements from your own script** (i.e. ignoring anything coming from imported modules).

```py
import logging.config

logging.config.dictConfig({
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'loggers': { '': {'level': 'INFO'} }
})

logging.info('Message from my own script')
```

Output:

```bash
INFO:root:Message from my own script
```

The level (`DEBUG`, `INFO`, `WARNING`, etc.) can be selected under the `loggers` object above. To further customize the format, have a look at the complete [configuration schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507825/where-is-a-complete-example-of-logging-config-dictconfig).

Answer (score -1):

Just change the lvl of the imported module loggers to higher than debug < warning or critical.