# Changing graphviz Log Level in Python

Tags: python, logging, graphviz, pygraphviz

I'm using the [Python graphviz](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library.
While my app is using one log level (e.g. `DEBUG`), I'd like to set the `graphviz` log level to something else (e.g. `WARNING`).

There is no `graphviz.set_loglevel()` function.
Is there a way to do this without temporarily changing the global log level?

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a direct answer, but we can do it at the module level as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56779634/135862).

```
logging.getLogger("graphviz").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```