# Redirect stout in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis using python.

```py
import ssl
import time
import base64
import string
import stomp


import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

log_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s]: %(message)s', datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

log_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename='healthCheck.log', when='midnight', interval=1, backupCount=15)

log_handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
logger = logging.getLogger('health_check_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # Set the desired logging level
logger.addHandler(log_handler)
class Listener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def on_error(self, message):
        print('received an error "%s"' % message.body)
       
    def on_message(self,message):
        print('received a message "%s"' % message.body)

def send_message(host, password):
    try:
        conn = stomp.Connection([(host,443)])
        conn.set_listener('', Listener())
        conn.set_ssl(for_hosts=[(host,443)], ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
        conn.connect('artemis', password, wait=True)
        conn.subscribe(destination='HealthCheck::HealthCheck', id=1, ack='auto')
        logger.info(f"Subscribed")
        conn.send(body="Hello World!", destination='HealthCheck::HealthCheck')
        time.sleep(2)
        conn.disconnect()
        return 1
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)
        return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    send_message("localhost", "any-password")
```

Now here if the host is down, for the statement `conn.connect()`, a line is printed in the terminal something as -

```
could not connect to host localhost, port 443
could not connect to host localhost, port 443
could not connect to host localhost, port 443
```

But I don't want this to be printed on stdout. I need only a returned value, i.e., 0 or 1, and if any exceptions as such should go in the log file.

How to run?
You don't need to run ActiveMQ or any such server, just install the libraries and run it.

Comment: You should consult the documentation or the issue tracker for the specific library that you are using.

Comment: Please [edit] and share a [mre]. Something that can be run as-is and without all the superficial stuff like logging.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the log level of an imported module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776086/changing-the-log-level-of-an-imported-module) Note: The logger name for the library you are using seems to be `stomp.py`, you can set the logging level to `ERROR` or higher to ignore that specific log.

Comment: Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat, this worked. I added `logging.getLogger("stomp").setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
`

Comment: Note: Given you can get the logger for the library you can also configure it to send the logs elsewhere like a file if you want to.