# warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") doesn't ignore logging.warning

Tags: python-3.x, logging, warnings, suppress-warnings

I am wondering why `warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")` cannot ignore all the warning messages. Is there anything required here?

```
>>> import logging
>>> import warnings
>>> warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
>>> logging.warn("This should not be printed")
WARNING:root:This should not be printed
>>>
```

Comment: see also [Python Logging - Disable logging from imported modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325042/python-logging-disable-logging-from-imported-modules)

Answer (score 2):

The `warning` module and `logging` module have intentionally separate filters. If you want to filter out the warning messages from the `logging` module you will have to use appropriate features from the `logging` module, like [filters](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects) or an appropriate `setLevel` call.

Comment: Thanks @avayert . Can you give a simple example.