# how to prevent the propagation of logging to other modules?

Tags: python, matplotlib, logging, python-logging

I made a logger in my python script (myscript.py),

```py
logfmt = '[%(asctime)s]{%(filename)s:%(lineno)d}[%(levelname)s] %(message)s'
datefmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'
formatter = logging.Formatter(logfmt, datefmt=datefmt)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format=logfmt, datefmt=datefmt)
logger = logging.getLogger(name='mine')
```

At INFO level, it looks ok. But at DEBUG level, it's strange matplotlib prints its logs showing a very long list of modules it imported. How to prevent it and print the logs of my script only?

```
[2021-07-27T11:53:48]{myscript.py:183}[INFO] ...

[2021-07-27T11:53:48]{__init__.py:224}[DEBUG] matplotlib data path: /home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data
[2021-07-27T11:53:48]{__init__.py:224}[DEBUG] CONFIGDIR=/home/user/.config/matplotlib
[2021-07-27T11:53:48]{__init__.py:1394}[DEBUG] matplotlib version 3.4.2
[2021-07-27T11:53:48]{__init__.py:1395}[DEBUG] interactive is False
[2021-07-27T11:53:48]{__init__.py:1396}[DEBUG] platform is linux
[2021-07-27T11:53:48]{__init__.py:1397}[DEBUG] loaded modules: ['sys', 'builtins', '_frozen_importlib', '_imp', '_warnings', '_frozen_importlib_external', '_io', 'marshal', 'posix', '_thread', '_weakref', 'time', 'zipimport', '_codecs', 'codecs', 'encodings.aliases', 'encodings', 'encodings.utf_8', '_signal', '__main__', 'encodings.latin_1', '_abc', 'abc', 'io', '_stat', 'stat', '_collections_abc', 
... very only list ...
'cycler', 'matplotlib.rcsetup', 'matplotlib._version', 'matplotlib.ft2font', 'kiwisolver', 'dateutil.rrule', 'matplotlib.units', 'matplotlib.dates']

[2021-07-27T11:53:48]{myscript.py:351}[INFO] ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Logging - Disable logging from imported modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325042/python-logging-disable-logging-from-imported-modules)

Comment: @blues no. and many comments of that A told that giving the logger a name doesn't change anything - same as my test.

Comment: Did you actually try? basicConfig adds a handler to the root logger, so the proposed solution does not work with basicConfig.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the logger used by `matplotlib`, then override its log level:

```
logging.getLogger(name='matplotlib').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Check [How to list all existing loggers using python.logging module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53250066/14637) if you want to know how I found out the name of the `matplotlib` logger (which happens to be the same name as the module and the package, but it doesn't have to be).

Answer (score 1):

Don't have a setup to try this, hopefully still works. After your logging config add:

```
mpl_logger = logging.getLogger(‘matplotlib’)
mpl_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the loglevel of matplotlib to "info"
see https://matplotlib.org/stable/_modules/matplotlib.html#set_loglevel