# Log everything from every module except one third party module

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I have a `main.py`:

```
import logging, sys
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG, 
    handlers=[logging.FileHandler("test.log"), logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)]
)  # log everything to file and stdout
logger = logging.getLogger("main")
logger.info("hello main!")

import thirdparty_module
thirdpary_module.foo()

import my_submodule1
```

which imports `my_submodule1`, `my_submodule2` ... `my_submodule9` that log a few things in DEBUG:

```
import logging 
logger = logging.getLogger("my_submodule1")
logger.debug("my_submodule1 debug test")
```

and a third party module `thirdparty_module.py` which I don't control, but that logs *too many things* in DEBUG:

```
import logging, time, threading
logger = logging.getLogger("thirdparty_module")

def foo():
    threading.Thread(target=bar).start()

def bar():
    while True:
        logger.debug(f"thirdparty_module {time.time()}")    # flood!!
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

**Question: how to keep DEBUG logging "ON" for `main.py`, `my_submodule1.py`, ..., `my_submodule9.py`, but avoid `thirdparty` to log anything in DEBUG?**

Note:

- I don't want to fork `thirdparty_module.py` to remove the `logging.setLevel(...)`.
- I have already read [Python Logging - Disable logging from imported modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35325042/python-logging-disable-logging-from-imported-modules) but it didn't fully cover this use case. Update: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57933716) answer helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the example is correct, then you can get `thirdparty.logger`. Logger objects have `propagate` attribute - this sets whether logs propagate to the upper loggers and their handlers. By default it's set to True, just switch it to False:

```
# main.py
...
import thirdparty_module
thirdparty_module.logger.propagate = False
thirdparty_module.foo()
...
```

Quick test:

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

l1 = logging.getLogger()
l2 = logging.getLogger("test")

l2.debug("test") # this prints

l2.propagate = False
l2.debug("test") # this doesn't print
```

Comment: Thanks @h4z3! Also I tried `thirdparty_module.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)` in `main.py` and it works too: everything from `thirdparty_module` will be limited to INFO and higher.